# Auto complete arcpy.da in VS Code

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, arcpy

I am attempting to switch to Visual Studio Code for my python scripting.  When accessing the data access module, the auto complete does not populate arcpy.da.

When I type arcpy.da.da the autocomplete populates with the functions/classes found in the module.  What gives with the extra da?

[arcpy.da](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT3hw.png)

[arcpy.da.da](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzVTl.png)

Comment: There might be some odd import semantics used by the library that are tripping it up. Are you using Jedi or the language server? If it's the former then try the language server by setting `"python.jediEnabled": true`.

Comment: Same happens to me with arcpy.da in pycharm. With the info "This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items"